# how to draw a continuous line with parted data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot to show the pattern of a series of data, say y here. The codes now are

```
y <- c(1:5,0,3:6)
x <- c(1:10)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
ggplot(data=data, mapping=aes(y=y, x=x,color= x>6)) +
  geom_line(size=1)+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

And the plot is
[image]
How can I draw a continuous line with parted data where the two points (x=6 and x=7) are connected with blue line? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Try `ggplot(data=data, mapping=aes(y=y, x=x,color= factor(ifelse(x == 6, 1, ifelse(x > 6, 2, 3))))) +
  geom_line(size=1)+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + aes(group = NA) + theme(legend.title = element_blank())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `group = 1` and change the condition to `x >= 6` to get blue line between the two points.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=data, mapping=aes(y=y, x=x, color = x >= 6, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(size=1)+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit on the logic behind it?

Comment: and can I change the legend label to 'large x'? Thank you~

Comment: `group = 1` is needed to identify that all the points are of the same group and should be connected. You can change the legend label using `+ scale_color_discrete(name = 'large_x')`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `geom_segment()`

```
y <- c(1:5,0,3:6)
x <- c(1:10)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
ggplot(data=data, mapping=aes(y=y, x=x,color= x>6)) +
  geom_line(size=1)+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_segment(x = 6, y=0, xend = 7, yend = 3, size=1) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]